# How to stop Django PasswordInput prefilling form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a django form to allow users to login.

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='User name', max_length=30)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'    
        widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

**views.py**

```
def login_view(request):
    form_context = {'login_form': LoginForm,}
    url = "users/login.html"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        ...
    else:
        context = form_context
    return render(request, url, context)
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ login_form.username.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ login_form.username }}</td>
            <td rowspan="2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ login_form.password.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ login_form.password }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The problem I have is that if the line

```
widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput()}
```

is used, then the form is pre-filled with username and password

If the line is commented out, the the form is not prefilled, but the password is in plain text.

What is wrong here?

Comment: That's a thing of your browser. Users can switch this on or off. Why wouldn't you want your users to have the form pre-filled with their credentials so they can quickly login? It only happens if you let your browser (or password manager) store your passwords.

Comment: So: Don't do it, it will make your website less secure because you're literally asking user to choose an easy to type, easy to remember password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to turn off autocomplete:

```
password = forms.PasswordInput(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))
```

or disable it for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: A sure way to get complaints from users who want to use secure passwords (different password for every website) and don't know their passwords. i.e. a sure way to get users choose bad passwords for your website.

Comment: Tell that to OP? I'm just answering the question.

Comment: I know, but a recommendation like: Do not do that! would be helpful here. It's bad for security of the web. Luckily password managers now start to ignore this autocomplete off BS.

Comment: How is typing your password manually less secure than using a password auto-filler?

Comment: Because: 1. I don't know my passwords, so I would have to look them up in the keychain. 2. my passwords are long (30+ characters) with lots of difficult characters. So forcing users to manually type their password means: I need a short, easy to remember password.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. Obviously opened a can of worms here